Symfony 7.1 fresh install with asset mapper / stimulus bundle gives "@hotwired/stimulus was a bare specifier" when rendering page
I am installing a new Symfony 7.1 / PHP 8.3.8 app with asset mapper and stimulus bundle and I am encountering issues with making stimulus functional :

symfony new my_project_directory --version="7.1.*" --webapp

check for the /config/routes/attributes.yaml file, otherwise create it as specified here https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes

create a base controller to render a basic twig file

add <div data-controller="hello"></div>in the rendered twig file.


When I load the page I have an error in the console Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “@hotwired/stimulus” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
boostrap.js file looks like this :
import { startStimulusApp } from '@symfony/stimulus-bundle';

const app = startStimulusApp();


hello_controller.js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';
export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        this.element.textContent = 'Hello Stimulus! Edit me in assets/controllers/hello_controller.js';
    }
}


and importmap.php
<?php
return [
    'app' => [
        'path' => './assets/app.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],
    '@symfony/stimulus-bundle' => [
        'path' => './vendor/symfony/stimulus-bundle/assets/dist/loader.js',
    ],
];


This issue is documented here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/asset_mapper.html#issues-and-debugging
But the provided solutions
php bin/console importmap:require @symfony/stimulus-bundle
or
php bin/console importmap:require @hotwired/stimulus
did not work for me as it returned
 [OK] 0 new items () added to the importmap.php
and I still have the same error even after a php bin/console cache:clear
I have also noticed that the generated importmap was slightly different than the documentation here so I tried to change
'@symfony/stimulus-bundle' => [
    'path' => './vendor/symfony/stimulus-bundle/assets/dist/loader.js',
],

to
'@symfony/stimulus-bundle' => [
    'path' => '@symfony/stimulus-bundle/loader.js',
],

But still no success
Am I missing a step ? I could use webpack but the server that we are going to use for deployment does not provide node/npm.
Thanks in advance for any tips

r.e. "was not remapped to anything", Your import map has no entry for '@hotwired/stimulus' look here: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/asset-mapper/stimulus#codeblock-068db5a3ec Did you allow the recipes to run?

my installation added  '@hotwired/stimulus' => [         'version' => '3.2.2',     ], at the import map file. yours did not? did you remove it?

sometimes symfony doc does not have the whole code but just the edts... maybe https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/last-stack/stimulus will be a better starting guide ...

Hello, thank you for the replies ; Indeed '@hotwired/stimulus' => ['version' => '3.2.2',    ] was missing from my installation, I did not remove it deliberately. I tried adding this line manually and then doing the import:map install command but it still returned 0 new items added. Ultimately I decided to get the source and remap @hotwired/stimulus to a path to a local file in my project, which did the trick.

The company I work at uses a different repo for the bundles, a different source for flex recipes and we work behind a proxy. It may be more of a config issue than a Symfony issue. I tried asking my colleagues if it could be related to that but still no answer for now...
